# Checkbox readonly / Disable according to status

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a dynamically created html table.In this table have check boxes.In here i use checkbox_status and if checkbox_status == 1 then checked a checkbox.

What i need to do is

> > If checkbox_status == 1 then i need to read only a that checkbox ( or disable that checkbox )

My Coding.(In here i put part of the codings )

```
var _html = "<table class='table table-bordered table-responsive refundfontcolor' id='newstable' style='background-color:#002060;color:white;'><thead><th>#</th><th>News Id:</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></thead><tbody>";
$.each(data, function (index, val) {
  debugger;
  checkbox_status = (val.IsReject == 1) ? 'checked' : '';
  _html += "<tr id=" + val.NewsId + " style='background-color:white;color:black'><td><input type='checkbox' " + checkbox_status + " id="   + val.NewsId + " ></td><td><p>" + val.Name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td><td><p>" + val.Description + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></td></tr>";
  $('#newstable').html(_html + "</tbody></table>");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will that work?

```
<input type='checkbox' " + checkbox_status + " id=" + val.NewsId + " "+(checkbox_status=='checked' ? 'disabled':'')+">
```